# Multiple has_manys of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, foreign-key-relationship

I have these models:

## Person

```
has_many :messages_form_person, :foreign_key => :from_user_id, :class_name => :messages
has_many :messages_to_person,     :foreign_key => :to_user_id, :class_name => :messages
```

## Message

```
belongs_to :to_person, :foreign_key     => :to_user_id, :class_name => :person
belongs_to :from_person, :foreign_key   => :to_user_id, :class_name => :person
```

And this view:

## person#show

```
<% @person.messages_to_person.each do |message| %>
  <%=h message.title %>
<% end %>
```

But I get this error:

> ## TypeError in People#show
>
> Showing app/views/people/show.html.erb where line #26 raised:
>
> ```
> can't convert Symbol into String
> ```
>
> Extracted source (around line **#26**):
>
> ```
> 23:   <%=h @person.biography %>
> 24: </p>
> 25: 
> 26: <% @person.messages_to_person.each do |message| %>
> 27: 
> 28: <% end %>
> 29:
> ```

I basically want it so that people can send each other messages.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `:class_name` should be a `string`

```
:class_name => "Message"
:class_name => "Person"
```

Comment: @j. I hate it that I must wait 10 minutes before I can accept an answer.

Comment: You have to wait? I'm sorry then :]